# How do I create a datasource and to connect this from R?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, datasource, sqldatasource

I don't know where are my code error. I created a datasource and after included in a RODBC function.

The datasource configuration is:

- Name: sqldatabases
- Driver: SQL Server Native Client 11.0
- Server: BRDCVMDB01
- Database in SQL Server: ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO

I hope you can help me!

Thank you!

**First Attempt**

```
library(RODBC)

connect <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=sqldatabases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
```

> Warning messages: 1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL
>   Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=databases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :   [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 53, message [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server [53].  2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection =
>   "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=databases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :   [RODBC] ERROR: state HYT00, code 0, message [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired 3: In
>   odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=databases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :   [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 53, message [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error
>   has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is
>   not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
>   information see SQL Server Books Online. 4: In
>   odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=databases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :   ODBC connection failed

**2nd Attempt**

```
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=databases;trusted_connection=yes;")
```

> Warning messages: 1: In for (i in seq_along(args)) { : closing unused
>   RODBC handle 14 2: In for (i in seq_along(args)) { : closing unused
>   RODBC handle 12 3: In for (i in seq_along(args)) { : closing unused
>   RODBC handle 8 4: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL
>   Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=databases;trusted_connection=yes;") :   [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 18456, message [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'ATRAME\mjordao'.
>   5: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=databases;trusted_connection=yes;") :   [RODBC] ERROR: state 42000, code 4060, message [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "databases"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. 6: In
>   odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=databases;trusted_connection=yes;") :   ODBC connection failed

**3rd Attempt**

```
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")

cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=sqldatabases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>       11.0};server=sqldatabases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :
>             [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 53, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server [53]. 
>           2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>       11.0};server=sqldatabases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :
>             [RODBC] ERROR: state HYT00, code 0, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
>           3: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>       11.0};server=sqldatabases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :
>             [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 53, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error
>   has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is
>   not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
>   information see SQL Server Books Online.
>           4: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>       11.0};server=sqldatabases;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
>   :
>             ODBC connection failed

Comment: Check you connection strings, they are pretty mixed up (database=databases?)

Comment: See [db.rstudio.com/dbi](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/)

Comment: Try `trusted_connection =no`. Sometimes its kind of wacky in R. Also, if you are running this in Linux, use ipaddress instead of `sqldatabases`

Answer (score 0):

I had ran into this error before, I would recommend check the actual running driver's name (for instance, mine is actually named SQL Server instead of the SQL Server Native Client, it took me a while to figure that out). And you want to make sure your SQL server is running.

And for the code, I recommend the following little changes :

Your original:

```
odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=databases;trusted_connection=yes;")
```

change to:

```
odbcDriverConnect('Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;server=BRDCVMDB01;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=TRUE;')
```

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 0):

With ODBC, there are two main ways to connect: either with a Data Source Name (DSN) which you indicate you use or a DSN-less driver version. In RODBC this differs with two methods `odbcConnect` and `odbcDriverConnect`. See *usage* section in [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/topics/odbcConnect).

Right now you conflate the two in running DSN-less driver connections but referencing a DSN. Simply connect with appropriate settings. Actually one of your coded lines (first of 3rd attempt) without warning messages should should have potentially worked:

```
# DSN CONNECTION
cn <-odbcConnect('sqldatabases;trusted_connection=yes')

# DRIVER CONNECTION
cn <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=BRDCVMDB01;database=ANALYTICS_FA_CP_SPRO;trusted_connection=yes;")
```